# React: Recommendations for making debugging easier when several filenames are index.{js,jsx}?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools, visual-studio-code

I was following the AirBnB style guide, which recommends making component filenames either the name of the `export` or `index.{js,jsx}`, but there are a few situations I ran into while doing it that greatly increased debugging difficulty:

1. (The worst) Console.log only identifies itself via the filename and cursor location:
   [image: console.log shows several index.jsx files, no way to know which one]
2. It's hard to know which `index.jsx` file you're opening in VS Code's file manager, because even if they're enclosed in a folder of the component name, when folders are nested VS Code will situate all the `index.jsx` files right next to each other if they're located in open sparsely-populated folders located in the same tree.

[image: VS Code file manager shown with several different index.jsx files]

3. The tab bar shows a bunch of files of the same name.  This is a little less important, since it shows the folder location if there's multiple files of the same name, but the folder names are written in smaller font, and their necessity makes the tab width wider, allowing fewer to display at a time.
4. It's harder to use the keyboard shortcuts to open files - if you have several files of the same name, typing in their filename to open them is severely hampered by an additional hunt-and-peck procedure required to navigate *which one* of them you need.

**What I did for an interim solution:**

I had to come up with a solution for my project quickly, so I named the `index.jsx` files the name of the `export`, despite already being in folders named the component name, resulting in "double-named" imports, like this:

[image: double-named esm imports]

**But**, this is *specifically frowned-upon* by the AirBnB styleguide, here's where it says explicitly NOT to do that: https://airbnb.io/javascript/react/#naming

[image: AirBnB telling me I'm oh so wrong, so very very wrong]

I guess I'll take the stink-eye from the AirBnB styleguide over having a lot more difficulty debugging for now, but has anyone come up with any good solutions to these problems so hopefully I can satisfy both our needs?

I'm thinking, maybe a chrome extension that shows more information about where `console.log()` messages are coming from, or a way to configure `vs-cde` so it makes the folder names more prominent on the tabs than the filenames if it detects multiples, etc.?

Comment: This question will likely be closed because really it's a matter of opinion. But remember the guide is just simply that - a guide. You can choose to ignore it if it makes your life easier.

Comment: I usually put each component in a subfolder with four files like: Header/Header.jsx, Header/Header.scss, Header.test.jsx, Header/index.js and then do both named and a default export from index. Then, I also have components/index.js where I export all of the components as named exports. That way, in my app, I do import {Header, Footer} from '../components'. In the tests, I reach in deep and get the direct export.

Comment: vscode does fuzzy matching, so you can type parts of the path and  filename to filter the list if you use the command pallette

Comment: finally, if you use named functions instead of anonymous functions, you will get a better debug experience. For the record, all arrow functions are anonymous, so it might take some work and/or getting used to.

Comment: @DovRine Thanks for your suggestions, great ideas.  I found a plugin that takes care of it using CRA, but I will definitely incorporate some of your methods, as well.  I answered my own question if you want to see what I did.

Comment: I disagree with this being a matter of opinion. The question is not asking about whether AirBnB's suggestions are good or bad, it asks about how to work with them, listing examples of potential solutions at the end ("chrome extensions that shows more information about where `console.log()` messages are coming from [...]"). Suggestiosn for how to debug more easily are hardly opinion based; they either help or they don't.

Comment: As rough (not full, because I cannot verify that myself atm) answer idea: At least in Firefox you can click the filename:line as a link which opens the debugger showing the code location the log originated from which would also help in finding the place where something came from.

Answer (score 0):

Whether this question gets closed or not, I hope it remains on the site, because this will undoubtedly be an issue for others going forward, and seems like more of a tooling issue than a style/opinion issue. Additionally, AirBnB's style guide is the defacto reference for idiomatic Javascript.

I did not go back to `index.js{x}` filenames in component-named folders, but instead stuck with the directory-named files and installed `directory-named-webpack-plugin` to resolve the issue of double-named imports.

This allowed me to have unique filenames without double-named imports, which is at least more adherent to the guide, and seems like the easiest way to avoid the negative effects of having several duplicate-named `index.js{x}` files.

I found the plugin through this feature request thread for `Microsoft/Typescript/jsconfig.json`: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24116#issuecomment-522339546

Unfortunately, it looks unmaintained, but it is for `webpack v4`, which is still current as of `CRA` `React 17.0.2`.  To my surprise, it worked fine as a drop-in with `create-react-app`.

Install and configure process was very easy.  Install the package as a dev dep:

```
$ npm i -D directory-named-webpack-plugin
```

Open the project's `node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js`, and add the default config for the package:

```
  var DirectoryNamedWebpackPlugin = require("directory-named-webpack-plugin");
 
  resolve: {
    plugins: [
      new DirectoryNamedWebpackPlugin()
    ]
  }
```

`webpack.config.js`'s file structure already exists, so only the two lines calling the plugin method need to be added. There's a lot of comments, so you have to navigate through hundreds of lines of code in order to put the directives in the right place, so I'll tell you the exact line numbers I used.

I put

```
const DirectoryNamedWebpackPlugin = require("directory-named-webpack-plugin");
```

(instead of `var`) at `line 15` just under `resolve()`, and

```
new DirectoryNamedWebpackPlugin()
```

went at `line 353` just under `PnpWebpackPlugin`.

And that was it.  Opened up the project, deleted the filenames from the folders of the same name, and they resolved immediately without any fanfare.

For reference, I ought to include my `jsconfig.json` file in case there's any cooperation happening - everything in here except the `"include":[]` line was generated by `jsconfig.json` cli package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "checkJs": false,
        "jsx": "react",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "module": "es2015",
        "target": "es2020",
        "baseUrl": "src",
        "include": ["src", "public"],
        "exclude": [
            "dist",
            "node_modules",
            "build",
            ".vscode",
            "coverage",
            ".npm",
            ".yarn"
        ],
        "typeAcquisition": {
            "enable": true,
            "include": ["react", "react-dom", "jest", "testing-library__jest-dom"]
        }
    }
}
```

I had a look at `esbuild` during this process, which looks very interesting and will have to try at some point, but at least for now I can go back to coding without looking at any ugly imports that arouse the ire of the omnipotent AirBnB.

Comment: Curious question: How does this solve the problem of only index.js(x) showing in dev tools? I think with that information, this answer would be nice and round!

Comment: Ah, maybe I wasn't clear enough - in the question I said I had re-named my index.jsx files to the same name as the component, but they're in folders with the same name as the component, so the "real" issue now is that they're double-named endpoints for the import statements.  I think that's kind of contrary to the question title unfortunately. Hm, how to fix...

Comment: Oooooh, so you are using imports in your code as if there was an index.js while there is no index.js? That makes it a bit more clear then, thanks!

Comment: Absolutely :) Glad I could help!